# JSON simple program showing error

Tags: json, struts2

Tyring a simple example of json but it is showing error.
  I have included gson-2.2.3.jar in class path.

I am using netbeans 7.1. This program is not deploying.

Apache tomcat log is showing:

```
 Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/D:/APP/webApp1/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:10:73
Caused by: Error building results for action sayHi in namespace  - action - file:/D:/APP/webApp1/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:10:73
Caused by: There is no result type defined for type 'json' mapped with name 'success'.  Did you mean 'json'? - result - file:/D:/APP/webApp1/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:11:33
```

I am trying simple example. Please see what is the proble.
Action Class

```
 public class AjaxActions extends ActionSupport {

    private String name;
    private String greeting;

    public String sayHi() {

        greeting = "HI " + name;
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }

    public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }
}
```

Struts.xml

```
<package extends="struts-default,json-default" name="ajax-package" namespace="/ajax">
    <action class="example.AjaxActions" method="sayHi" name="sayHi">
        <result type="json">
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

in jsp file

```
<form action="" id="introForm">
            <label for="name">Enter Your Name</label>
            <input name="name">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <script>
            $(function(){

                $("#introForm").submit(function(){

                var formInput=$(this).serialize();
                $.getJSON('ajax/sayHi.action', formInput,function(data) {

                $('.result').html('' + data.greeting + '');
                return false;

                });

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Try adding the getters and setters for name and greeting in your action class

Comment: It was already there. I forget to include it. Not working

Comment: Try changing your struts package to only extend json-default

Comment: Now it is deploying but not giving any result

Comment: Your action class has package 'example' right? any errors on console? try using the network tab on Chrome Dev Tools or similar to analyze the ajax call

Comment: So steps are ok. I found many json jar files which should we use for struts2. are can we use any. for are the process is same or it depends on json jar files

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32989/discussion-between-user2302288-and-koala-dev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `struts2-json-plugin.jar` according to struts2 version in your project libraries. 
if you are using  struts2.3.4 then use struts2-json-plugin2.3.4.jar

And change your in your `struts.xml`

`<package extends="struts-default,json-default"`
 to 
 `<package extends="json-default"`.

And use the  following html code.

```
    <form action="" id="introForm">
                <label for="name">Enter Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                <input onclick="javascript:getResultData();" type="submit">
           <span id="resultHtml"></span>
 </form>
            <script>
                function getResultData(){
                    var formInput=$("#name").val();
                    vat inputData={"name":formInput}
                    $.getJSON('ajax/sayHi.action', inputData,function(data) {

                    $("#resultHtml").html('' + data.greeting + '');
                    return false;

                    });
                   }

            </script>
```

Comment: @user2302288 I have updated the answer.. try this one it ll help.

Comment: I tried now it is working properly.  I am using struts2.3.4 for that we have to include struts2-jsonplugin 2.3.4.jar. Then it will work properly.It was only the problem of jar file.